# Pass an argument through one function to another function

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I'm writing a PHP Wordpress plugin where I want to be able to call the functions I've defined in other parts of my website (e.g. on page templates).

I want to be able to pass arguments to my functions like so:

```
// Contained on Page Template to display content

$args1 = 'Hello';
$args2 = 'Goodbye';

saySomething( $args1, $args2);

// Contained within plugin file

function saySomething ($args1, $args2){

  //echo $args1 //Test Only
  //echo $args2 //Test Only

  function sayHello () {
      echo $args1;
  }

  function sayGoodbye () {
    echo $args2;
  }
}
```

I've already use 'include_once' to make sure I can call functions in my plugin file. However, for some reason the sub-functions (for want of a better word!) don't seem to work. I've tried a few things, including redefining the arguments within the first function (e.g. $newargs = $args1). Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

Comment: You aren't calling the "sub-functions" anywhere in there.

Comment: Also, `$args1` and `$args2` are not defined in their scope.

Comment: How about class and methods?

Comment: There's no such thing as "sub-functions", simply functions defined within another function; but they're still created in the global scope, and standard function scoping rules still apply

Comment: Thanks @Don't Panic. This is what I've done. What do you think?

`function saySomething ( $args1, $args2){
 
 $args3 = $args1;
 $args4 = $args2;
 
 echo $args3;
 echo $args4;
 
 function sayHello ( $args3) {
  echo $args3;
 }
 sayHello( $args3);
 
 function sayGoodbye ( $args4) {
  echo $args4;
 }
 sayGoodbye( $args4);
}`

@Hackerman - I think Classes / Methods are definitely a better method. Better go and learn what they are now ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of main things.

1. You've defined the `sayHello` and `sayGoodbye` functions, but they are not called.
2. `sayHello` and `sayGoodbye` refer to variables `$args1` and `$args2`, but those variables are [undefined within their scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Here's a way to make it work with minimal changes to your code. I changed the names of the variables to emphasize the fact that the variables in `sayHello` and `sayGoodbye` are not the same variables as the ones in `saySomething`.

```
function saySomething ($args1, $args2){

  function sayHello ($x) {   // update the function signature so that it takes an argument
      echo $x;               // use the given parameter
  }

  function sayGoodbye ($y) {
    echo $y;
  }

  // call the functions
  sayHello($args1);
  sayGoodbye($args2);
}
```

One other thing:

Contrary to what it looks like, `sayHello` and `sayGoodbye` are available in the same scope as `saySomething`. They are *not* defined only within the scope of that function, even though they are written there. In effect it's the same thing as writing:

```
function saySomething ($args1, $args2){
  sayHello($args1);
  sayGoodbye($args2);
}

function sayHello ($x) {
  echo $x;
}

function sayGoodbye ($y) {
  echo $y;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Don't Panic. This is brilliant and works very well. Thank you. 

Thank you also for the explanation that the 'sayHello' and 'sayGoodbye' functions are actually defined outside of the 'saySomething' function. It's really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

To use inner functions in PHP, you have to pass scope explicitly:

```
$args1 = 'Hello';
$args2 = 'Goodbye';

$saySomething = function() use ($args1, $args2) {
    $sayHello = function() use ($args1) {
        echo $args1;
    };
    $sayGoodbye = function() use ($args2) {
        echo $args2;
    };
    $sayHello();
    $sayGoodbye();
};
```

It's not like JavaScript where the scope gets passed along automamagickally:

```
let args1 = 'Hello';
let args2 = 'Goodbye';

let saySomething = () => {
    let sayHello = () => {
        console.log(args1);
    };
    let sayGoodbye = () => {
        console.log(args2);
    };
    sayHello();
    sayGoodbye();
};
```

Comment: Great. So I think this secondary answer is a bit above my skill level, but for the benefit of future readers you'd define functions in this way `$sayHello = function() use ($args1)` if you wanted them to be anonymous functions which are only available within the 'saySomething' function?